# What does this line of ruby do?

Tags: ruby

I stumbled upon this line of Ruby in our codebase:

```rb
value = value.to_i if value == value.to_i
```

and I can't understand what it is supposed to do.

If the guard condition is false, it does nothing.
If it is true, it's a noop.

What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line of code will cast any integer number to the `Integer` class, so it will replace `2.0` or `BigDecimal(2)` with `2`.  This might be useful if you have code later on which cares about the class of `value`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a noop in most cases. However, in cases where `value` doesn't respond to `to_i`, a `NoMethodError` will be thrown - I very much doubt that this is intentional, but without more context it's difficult to be more precise.